# Two Xamarin.Forms.Shapes lines on top of each other, top line is casting a 'shadow' (only on iOS)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am drawing an X shape with two `Xamarin.Forms.Shapes.Line`s in an AbsoluteLayout.
On the iOS simulator (iPhone 12 iOS 14.5) the top line (the one being drawn second) looks like it casts some sort of shadow on the line on the bottom. On Android everything seems to be working just fine.

**Update**
I created a very simple project demonstrating this problem. You can download it [here](https://gitlab.com/luwesch/xam-forms-line-test) (GitLab link).

Here are screenshots (in one file) of what you will see when running this program. The left screenshot is from an Android emulator (Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 API 28), the right screenshot is from an iOS simulator (iPhone 12 iOS 14.5). [Said screenshot (left Android, right iOS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OEvm.png).
The issue I am describing is in my opinion clearly visible even without zooming. As stated: Android works as expected, iOS does not.

**End of update**

It looks like this (heavily zoomed in):
[White X from two lines, top line casting a shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3obER.png).

**I have two questions:**

**Why is this happening?**

**Is there a simple way to prevent this?**
Line doesn't have any kind of shadow, so I guess it's something else but I can't find a solution or anyone else having this problem. As stated above, Android looks fine.

Here is a stripped down/modified version of my current code.

Xaml

```
...
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="MyX"
                WidthRequest="32"
                HeightRequest="32"/>
...
```

Code-behind

```
        ...

        // Constructor
        public MyPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyX.SizeChanged += drawX;
        }

        private void drawX(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            var container = (AbsoluteLayout)sender;
            double width = container.Width;
            double height = container.Height;
            double offset = container.Width * 0.3;

            // X: Line property values
            PenLineCap lineCap = PenLineCap.Round;
            double strokeThickness = 2;
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.White);

            // X: Top left to bottom right
            Line line1 = new Line {
                X1 = container.X + offset,
                Y1 = container.X + offset,
                X2 = container.X + width - offset,
                Y2 = container.X + height - offset,
                Stroke = brush,
                StrokeLineCap = lineCap,
                StrokeThickness = strokeThickness,
            };

            // X: Bottom left to top right
            Line line2 = new Line {
                X1 = container.X + offset,
                Y1 = container.X + height - offset,
                X2 = container.X + width - offset,
                Y2 = container.X + offset,
                Stroke = brush,
                StrokeLineCap = lineCap,
                StrokeThickness = strokeThickness
            };

            container.Children.Add(line1);
            container.Children.Add(line2);

        }
```

Comment: What's the `offset`, `width` and `height` ? If it is convinient for you ,could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I added more code to make the example more complete. The source of the values for `offset`, `width` and `height` are now included in the `drawX` function.  
I certainly can post a demo, would you like this to be a full working solution reproducing the problem?

Comment: I did a test based on your code on iOS simulator (iPhone 12 iOS 14.5)  , but I couldn't find the shadow you mentioned.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks for testing on your end. I added a link to a simple repo reproducing this problem and the problem persists. I added screenshots of the program running on Android and iOS. It can be seen without zooming that the top line is casting some sort of shadow (only on iOS).

Comment: Thanks for your responce. Due to the different rendering implementations on Android and iOS platforms, the effect will be different. For this problem, you can post a request here: github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues .